# Bayesian Optimization with XGBoost error: "Some trailing characters could not be parsed: 'Inf' "

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to replicate this method using a different dataset in R.

https://www.kaggle.com/btyuhas/bayesian-optimization-with-xgboost

My data has missing values, but no Inf values. However, it gives me the error message:

Error in xgb.iter.update(fd$bst, fd$dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  Some trailing characters could not be parsed: 'Inf'

Timing stopped at: 0.39 0.19 0.58

I searched online but couldn't find relevant answers.

Thank you!

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(x_train), label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(x_test))


xgb_evaluate = function(max_depth, gamma, colsample_bytree){
  params = list(max_depth = max_depth,
                subsample = 0.8, 
                eta = 0.1,
                gamma = gamma,
                colsample_bytree = 0.3,
                eval_metric = "rmse")

  # Used around 1000 boosting rounds in the full model
  cv_result = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, nround=100, nfold=3)    

  # Bayesian optimization only knows how to maximize, not minimize, so return the negative RMSE
  return (-1.0 *tail(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log$test_rmse_mean, 1))
}


xgb_bo = BayesianOptimization(xgb_evaluate, 
                              bounds = list(max_depth = c(4L, 6L),
                                            gamma = c(0, 1), 
                                            colsample_bytree = c(0.3, 0.9)), 
                              n_iter = 20)
```

Comment: Are there any `NA`s, infinite values or `NaN`s in your data? Run the expression: `sum(is.na(x_train) | !is.finite(x_train))` . It should return 0.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rohit. Since my x_train is a dataframe, I ran this: 
sum(is.na(as.matrix(x_train)) | !is.finite(as.matrix(x_train))).  It is not 0, because I do have NA values in my data. How should I handle the NA values? My understanding is that XGboost can handle NA values.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I tried include only the complete cases in the x_train, but ran into the same error.

Comment: Have you also removed infinite values? If you used `complete.cases()` then it would only remove `NA`s, but not `Inf`. Try `x_train <- x_train[is.finite(rowSums(x_train)),]`